# elapsed time taken and status of Logstash Pipe

Tags: logstash

Please help me out to find the elapsed time from pipe started between pipe ended and its status whether it is completed or not. Please help to store the status of the pipe and time taken by the pipe

Comment: My code as below

Comment: Where is the code? Add your code first.